# using try catch with my menu program

Tags: c#

I created a player class and made a array from that class for my menu driven player system I am trying to use try catch to catch the exception if the number entered for the player number, goals or assists is  a negative number and then display the message Number must have a positive value but for some reason it isn't catching the exception.

Any help would be appreciated

```
//Creates a player in the tables if the array is not already full and the name is not a duplicate
static void ProcessCreate(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals,
    Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)

{
    string message;
    //Int32 player = 0;

    if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
    {
        try
        {
            number = IOConsole.GetInt32("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's number: ");
            //number = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
            //(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nNumber must have positive value");
        }
        if (GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount) == -1)
        {
            message =("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's First Name: ");
            firstName = IOConsole.Getstring(message);
                //Console.ReadLine();
            message = ("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's Last  Name: ");
            lastName = IOConsole.Getstring(message);
                //Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                goals = IOConsole.GetInt32("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's goals: ");

            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nNumber must have positive value");
            }
                //goals = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
                //Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            try
            {
                assists = IOConsole.GetInt32("\nCreate Player: please enter the player's assists: ");
                //assists = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
                //Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nNumber must have positive value");
        }

            InsertPlayer(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}\n", "Number", "First Name", "Last Name", "Goals", " Assists", "Points");
            for (Int32 player = 0; player < playerCount; player++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}",
            players[player].Number, players[player].FirstName, players[player].LastName,
            players[player].Goals, players[player].Assists, players[player].Points());


            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");

}
```

> Here is my Number, Goal and Assist from my Player class if needed

```
//Public Number accessor
public Int32 Number
{
    get
    {
        //Return member variable value
        return _number;
    }
    set
    {
        //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
        if (value <=  0)
            throw new Exception("Invalid Player Number");
        else
            //Otherwise set member variable value
            _number = value;
    }
}

//Public Goals accessor
public Int32 Goals
{
    get
    {
        //Return member variable value
        return _goals;
    }
    set
    {
        //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
        if (value <= 0)
            throw new Exception("Goals must be a positive number");
        else
            //Otherwise set member variable value
            _goals = value;
    }
}



//Public Assits accessor
public Int32 Assists
{
    get
    {
        //Return member variable value
        return _assists;
    }
    set
    {
        //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
        if (value <= 0)
            throw new Exception("Assits must be a positive number");
        else
            //Otherwise set member variable value
            _assists = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: "it isn't catching the exception." -- _what_ isn't catching _which_ exception? You really need better exception handling generally: catch _specific_ exceptions (i.e. those you except to get and know how to handle), not `Exception`. But it's not clear at all in your question what line of code you think is/should be throwing an exception, nor what exception you think it is or should be. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please don't write code with `catch (Exception)`. It's probably even worse than using a `goto`. Exceptions should be something exceptional. Someone entering a negative number isn't exceptional. You should just handle that situation in normal code - not a try/catch block. You're just going to make your code hard to reason about and to debug. Catching exceptions like this is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell in this code, you you have `Int32` Properties on your `Player` Class for `Number`, `Goals`, and `Assists`, where you throw an Exception on assignment.  You are trying to Catch exceptions when you read the input in; however, your input coming in is just being stored in a standard `Int32` variable.  The exceptions you are throwing are not happening until you assign these variables to an instance of a player, which happens much later, outside of these `catch` statements.  The application is likely still throwing the Exceptions, but they are happening inside the `InsertPlayer` Method, not the method where you listed the `catch` statements.

Also, it seems odd that you are passing variables in to this function only to fill those variables with console data.  Either the value is coming from the function call or from the console, but not both.  It seems to me that you don't need the variables in the function signature and they can be declared locally.